# ExtJs select component by itemId starting with a string

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

Using Ext Js 4.1.

I have multiple checkboxes in panel with ids and itemIds: 'chA104', 'chA204', 'chB111' etc.
And I want to get all checkboxes that starts with id (or itemId) = 'chA' to make them disabled.

How to do that?
Tryed to use this:

```
this.query('*[id^=chA]');
```

But get an array with multiple elements: table, td, input etc.
When doing this:

```
Ext.query('input[id^=chA]')[0]
```

I get an html input element. But when trying to do:

```
Ext.query('input[id^=chA]')[0].disable();
Ext.query('input[id^=chA]')[0].setDisabled(true);
```

I get an error.

So how to get all checkboxes, starting with a string id (or itemId) and make them enabled/disabled?

Comment: Please, create an example on Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using extjs checkboxes, you could do it like this:

```
//enable/disable
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('checkboxfield{id.search("chA")!=-1}')[0].disable(); 
//check/uncheck                           
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('checkboxfield{id.search("chA")!=-1}')[0].setValue(true);
```

if is pure html just use:

```
//enable/disable
Ext.query('input[id^=chA]')[0].disabled = true;
//check/Uncheck
Ext.query('input[id^=chA]')[0].checked = true;
```